# how to get a string without \n \t?

Tags: objective-c

In object -c, I get a string such as "\n\n\t\n\t http://www.stackoverflow.com",but what i want is the string "http://www.stackoverflow.com",how to get it?

Answer (score 6):

`[myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]` will give you your string with any leading or trailing newlines and spaces (including tabs) removed. It'll remove the "\n\n\t\n\t " from your sample string, but if that string were to have, say, a space or newline character in the middle of it, that would not get removed. If you want to remove *all* such characters from the string, not just the ones at the beginning and end, you probably have to do something messy like using the `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` method and rebuilding the string from the array that that returns.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regular expression search-and replace: Search for `^\s*` and replace with nothing.

Comment: See: http://borkware.com/quickies/single?id=399 and Noah's answer. Much more efficient than a regex, assuming only the characters at the start or end need to be trimmed.  If whitespace in the middle needs to be trimmed, then a regex would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT | Sorry, mis-read your question)

You'll have to post the code.  Where is this string coming from?  If you defined it as NSString then it should not do this.  If those \n etc are in a file that's being read, such as a plist or a web document, then they will be interpreted literally, including the backslash.